# Angularjs arrays with 1 variable won't print with ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, arrays

I'm new to angularjs and I've encountered a pretty annoying problem.
In my app I'm using a factory that holds all the functions, and let the controllers use them.
I created a function that's returning an array and printing it on the web page, 
but when the returned array contains only 1 variable, it prints sort of an empty list. it works fine when there's more than 1 variable in the array.
console.log shows that the array contains the variable, but it won't print it on my list.

I'm also using bootstrap if that matters.

I hope I explained my problem properly.
Thanks for the help!

Factory:

```
       function getArray(var){
        return $http.get(restURL+var).then(
                function(response){
                    return response.data.coupon;
                }
        );
    }
```

Controller:

```
         $scope.getArrayFunction = function(){
         appServicesProvider.getArray($scope.var).then(function(coupons){
             $scope.arrayVar = coupons;
         })
     }
```

HTML:

```
<div id="getArrayDiv">     
        <table class="table table-hover">
         <thead>
           <tr>
             <th>#</th>
             <th>&nbsp;Title</th>
             <th></th>
           </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody>
           <tr ng-repeat="coupon in arrayVar">
             <td>{{coupon.id}}</td>
             <td>{{coupon.title}}</td>
           </tr>
         </tbody>
   </table>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Type" ng-model="var" required="true">

    <button  class="btn  btn-success" ng-click="getArrayFunction()"  >Get Array</button>
 </div> <!-- /getArrayDiv -->
```

Comment: have you used ng-app directive anywhere in your html ?

Comment: Yes, of course. As I said, everything works perfectly, the only problem is when the returned array contains only 1 variable.

Comment: @DorGolan can you do {{arrayVar}} and show how that 1 variable looks like in html

Comment: Looks like `coupons` is a object and not array

Comment: @MaximShoustin I see now that the array containing 1 variable is actually an object, but when there's more than 1 variable it's an array. My java code returns an array, and arrayVar is defined as an array, so I'm not sure what to make of this.. any ideas what I should do?

Comment: @DorGolan please post JSON what you see under `response.data`

Comment: @MaximShoustin I apologize but I'm not sure what you're asking, note that I'm still new to angularjs :) I do appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your API is returning an object (instead of array) when there is only one record to return and an array when there is more than one records.

So, here is workaround, just replace your return statement of factory's method with below statement, it should work fine.

```
return [].concat(response.data.coupon);
```

Here is the reference link to know more about `concat` function: https://www.w3schools.com/jsreF/jsref_concat_array.asp

Hope this work for your question. Cheers!

Comment: This actually works! It's the first time I see the concat() function so I wasn't sure what it does and wanted to do some reading, but it turns out great.
Is it considered a quickfix or a legit way to solve my problem?

Comment: `concat` function merges passed array or json objects and returns the final result.  Here  is the ref link of w3Schools https://www.w3schools.com/jsreF/jsref_concat_array.asp
It's a working solution (not a temporary fix).

Comment: It says that concat is used to join two arrays, so I'm not sure how it solved my problem, but it does.

Comment: Correct, javascript converts object into an array internally, when `concat` function parameter is an object.

Comment: My pleasure! Always happy to help the people.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are not Calling your function, please call your function after you declared it in this way

```
$scope.getArrayFunction();
```

Comment: I am calling the function - ng-click="getArrayFunction()",
Also, the function works with arrays with more than one variable, so I don't that's the problem.

Comment: please add "Console.log($scope.arrayVar)" after "$scope.arrayVar = coupons;" in your function and write the result from your browser's console here